# How to install LXML Python 3.3 Windows 8 64 Bit

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I think I'm too stupid for installing LXML Lib on my System.
Please can anyone help me with instructions for stupid people?
I found a lot of instruction, but they did not help me much.

I looked at LXML-Homepage 
For installation I need pip 1.4.1? I downloaded it... But, how can I install it?

```
Unzip pip-1.4.1.tar.gz
```

Then I opened the setup.py with my Python Shell.
Run the modul:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\................\dist\pip-1.4.1\setup.py", line 5, in <module>
    from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named 'setuptools'
```

Ok.. now I thought I need setuptools...
Downloaded `setuptools-1.4.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl`
Unziped it.. run the `easy_install.py` with my python shell

```
SystemExit: error: No urls, filenames, or requirements specified
```

Same error if started in windows command console.
What should I do?

Comment: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Comment: Yes. @Aleksei is correct. A more direct links is: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml and from there you select your .whl file based upon your OS and then you can run something like: **pip install lxml-3.5.0-cp35-none-win32.whl**

Answer (score 5):

If you on Windows, why not to use binary packages with normal installers?
You can find them on this page: http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

Answer (score 4):

You can also use anaconda. Once you have it installed (http://continuum.io/downloads) you can just run `conda install lxml` to install lxml. It's also very useful for packages like numpy and scipy, which can sometimes be a pain to install on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

**These instructions are for Windows7 or Windows8 with Python3.3** specifically as the original poster requested.  **However**, they should work for various versions as the releases of python and other respective prerequisites change/evolve:

1. Install ***Python3.3***:

   1. Download the last release of Python3.3 (currently 3.3.5) from the downloads page [HERE](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-335/)

      - Direct link for Win32 MSI installer -> [HERE](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/python-3.3.5.msi)
      - Direct link for Win64 MSI installer -> [HERE](http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.3.5/python-3.3.5.amd64.msi)
   2. Simply run the MSI to install python.  It will register itself in the registry, and appear in Add/REmove Programs.
   3. **NOTE:** my instructions that follow assume that you choose to install python to the default path of `C:\python33\` when asked during the Python Installation Wizard
2. Add the `C:\python33\` and `C:\python33\scripts` folders to the system path by adding those directories to the `PATH` environment variable from the **Control Panel > System > Advanced System Settings link (Advanced Tab) > Environmental Variables (Button)**.
3. Install ***OpenSSL***:

   1. Download **Win32 OpenSSL page** from [HERE](http://slproweb.com/products/Win32OpenSSL.html) for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   2. Download **Visual C++ 2008 redistributables** for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   3. Download **OpenSSL** for your version of Windows and architecture (the regular version, not the light one)
   4. Add the `c:\openssl-win32\bin` (or similar) directory to your `PATH`, the same way you added `C:\python33` and `C:\python33\scripts` above.
4. Install ***Setuptools*** (`get-pip.py` should install Setuptools for you), but, just in case...

   1. Download `ez_setup.py` [HERE](https://bitbucket.org/pypa/setuptools/raw/bootstrap/ez_setup.py) and save it in `C:\python33\scripts`
   2. Run **`C:\python33\scripts> python ez_setup.py`**
5. Install ***PIP***

   1. Download `get-pip.py` from [HERE](https://raw.github.com/pypa/pip/master/contrib/get-pip.py) and save it in `C:\python33\scripts`
   2. Run **`C:\python33\scripts> python get-pip.py`**
6. Install ***LXML***

   1. Download `LXML 3.3.3` from [HERE](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.3.3) for your version of Windows and PC architecture
   2. Run the EXE file

Answer (score 0):

Download lxml based on your version dependencies from here,

http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/djcobkfp/lxml-3.4.4-cp27-none-win32.whl # replace lxml version based on your dependencies..
    http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ 
and open your command prompt open lcoation Downloads or where file Downloaded in cmd..

that install using,

```
pip install lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl # this is eg name may vary based on your python or lxml version.
```