# How to install lxml on Windows 8 64-bit with Python 3.4

Tags: windows-8, lxml, python-3.4

[Related Question 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23944465/installing-lxml-for-python-3-4-on-windows-x-86-32-bit-with-visual-studio-c-2)
[Related Question 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20244943/how-to-install-lxml-python-3-3-windows-8-64-bit)

[Error Log]

C:\Users\Hima\Documents\Installers\python\packages>python -m pip install lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl
lxml-3.4.4-cp34-none-win_amd64.whl is not a supported wheel on this platform.

[Environment]

Windows x86 (64-bit)
Installed Visual Studio C++ 2014
Python 3.4
I use pip (or pip3.4.exe; built-in to Python 3.4) to pip install lxml

[Issues]
1. The lxml file from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml shows as not supported.
2. In the following Package Index for lxml, there isn't a suitable lxml file for 64 bit and Python 3.4.
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/lxml/3.4.4

Answer (score 2):

I have been struggling with this today.  I found, elsewhere on stackoverflow.com, this two-part and quick solution, which resulted in python no longer complaining when I tried to use lxml:

1. Go to [this repository](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml) and download a version which matches your Python installation (the version number, and 32- vs 64-bit.  I use Python 3.5.1 64-bit, installed on Windows 10, so on that page, I chose **lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**.

You say you use Python 3.4, so use a version that matches that (or maybe the one you already have).

There is some helpful information at the top of the [page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/) about which version of CPython the files are built against.

The output of `python -v` will also tell you which version of MSVC++ was used to build your version of the python executable.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70630/726378) is useful for determining MSVC versions from the output of `python -v` (which contains a build number instead of a version number).

My download directory is d:\Downloads.  Python must be in your PATH environment variable for the next step to work.  Use a command like the following, changing "D:\Downloads" to the pathname to your download directory.  Then, at a DOS prompt, type:

2. **python -m pip install "D:\Downloads\lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl" lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl**

Comment: It complained at me when I added the file name after the path to the file, but it worked.

Comment: I am using Python 2.7, but the above information was helpful to me.

Comment: This method helped me install lxml nicely on my win10 64 bit system with python 3.4

Answer (score 0):

My config:
Python 3.5
Windows 10

Downloaded **lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl** from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#lxml

Copy this file to: `c:\Program Files\Python35\`

first in cmd line:
    `c:\Program Files\Python35>py -m pip install --upgrade pip`

Then in cmd line:
    `c:\Program Files\Python35>py -m pip install lxml-3.6.0-cp35-cp35m-win_amd64.whl`

And it's done